# Changing citation reference systems

Tags: citations, citation-style, reference-managers

I am writing a research paper for the first time and I submitted my paper to a journal, in which the references in my paper were addressed in parentheses, as follows:

".....be preferentially located in the nuclear interior (Saccone et al. 2002; Cremer et al. 2015), consistent with a less compact organization and an enrichment of long-range chromosomal contacts with other active TADs and potentially multi-TAD hubs (Yaffe and Tanay, 2011; Olivares-Chauvet et al. 2016)."

The journal rejected it, and I submitted it to another journal which wants the references as follows:

".....be preferentially located in the nuclear interior [1-2], consistent with a less compact organization and an enrichment of long-range chromosomal contacts with other active TADs and potentially multi-TAD hubs [3-4]."

1. Saccone et al. 2002
2. Cremer et al. 2015
3. Yaffe and Tanay, 2011
4. Olivares-Chauvet et al. 2016

In the current format I have, all my references have the name and year in the parentheses and the full references at the end of the manuscript. The new journal wants it as numbers in order of occurrence in the manuscript.

Does anyone know any easy way to change the formats, without buying any software? If this question is out of scope of this forum, is there an appropriate one where I should ask?

Any help would be hugely appreciated, thank you so much!

Cheers,

Comment: Oh, nobody told you to not do these things by hand? References are so much easier to manage with computer programs...

Comment: Hi Wolfgang, thanks for your reply! Do you have any solution to this? Which software program can I use that can convert it automatically? Thanks!

Comment: EndNote, bibtex, and basically every one that's out there allows you to use a "style file". Changing the style is as easy as loading a different style file.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to switch from one reference style to another is to manage the references using softwares. You may use [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/?interaction_required=true) or [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/), which are free reference management softwares. [EndNote](https://endnote.com/) is another option but you need to purchase it. [A free version of EndNote](https://belmont.libguides.com/endnote/basic) with basic functionality is also available.

Comment: If you use LaTeX, use bibtex as your reference manager.

Comment: Can it automatically do it for me by processing my the references in between parentheses and convert them into this format in word?

Comment: @rishi: Yes,  but first you have to create a library containing all the references used in your  manuscript and cite the references using the software. Then,  changing from one style to another is automatic.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you recommend Zotero?

Comment: @rishi: It depends on your preference and which one you find more user-friendly.